# Как добавлять в пустой список элементы из файла?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct el {
    string data;
    el *adres;
};
class List {
  private:
    el * fadr, *eadr;

  public:
    List() {
    fadr = NULL;
    eadr = NULL;
    } void fadd(string a) {
    el *v;
    v = new el;
    v->data = a;
    v->adres = fadr;
    fadr = v;
    }

    void print() {
    if (fadr == NULL) {
        cout << "List is emptyn";
        return;
    }
    el *v;
    for (v = fadr; v != NULL; v = v->adres)
        cout << v->data << " ";
    cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    List s1;
    s1.print();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Вот создал пустой список, а сейчас хочу, чтобы при нажатии на клавишу "А" добавлялись элементы в список. Сделал так:

```
char v = getch();
if (v == 'a')
    s1.fadd("Hi");
s1.print();
```

Все отлично, работает. А как сделать, чтобы, он брал эти элементы из файла? Чтобы при повторном нажатии на "A", он из файла поочередно брал элементы и выводил в качестве результата?

Comment: Что мешает Вам сделать то, что Вы написали?

Answer (score 3):

Вместо `s1.fadd("Hi");` нужно вставить блок кода, который считывает строчку из файла и добавляет её.

Comment: дело в том, что в файлах я слабо разбираюсь. Можешь ты мне образец написать?

Comment: @navi1893 прочитайте об этом в книжке или интернете.

Comment: Можете мне объяснить, ("input.in") и ("output.out")? Сюда название файла написать или как?

    #include <fstream>
    int main()
    {
        std::ifstream input("input.in");
        int number;
        input >> number;
        number += 45;
        std::ofstream output("output.out");
        output << number;
    }

Comment: @navi1893 все правильно написано, [Ввод-вывод с файлами](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) на сайте `cplusplus.com`.

Comment: input.in и output.out это сами файлы. input.in открыт для чтения, а output.out для записи.

Comment: @navi1893, 

    Можете мне объяснить, ("input.in") и ("output.out")? Сюда название файла написать или как?

просто побольше  экспериментируйте с подобными штуками. 

Пишите код, **запоминаете, что хотите увидеть**, запускаете, смотрите что получилось, обдумываете результат и т.д.